# выборка из трёх таблиц с GROUP BY и ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

магазин с категориями товаров

необходимо для каждой категории (отсортированных по популярности) выбрать один товар (отсортированных по популярности),
но так как товары могут повторяться от категории к категории, необходимо выборку товаров сделать уникальной.

есть три таблицы:

категории:

```
cats
id,name,popularity
```

товары:

```
items
id,name,popularity
```

таблица связей:

```
cats2items
cat_id, item_id
```

на выходе нужно получить вроде:

```
cat_id   item_id
1          5
3          1
2          56
10         177
```

мильон вариантов перепробовал, вот последний:

```
SELECT cats2items.cat_id, i.item_id
FROM cats2items
 inner join (
  select items.id, items.popularity
  FROM items
  ORDER by items.popularity DESC
  ) i
WHERE cats2items.item_id = i.id
AND cats2items.cat_id IN (SELECT cats.id FROM cats ORDER BY cats.popularity DESC)
GROUP BY cats2items.cat_id
```

но товары получаются не уникальными и они не отсортированы по популярности:

```
cat_id   item_id
1          86
2          3
3          1
4          49
5          3
```

подскажите куда копать плиз

Comment: А к какой из групп следует относить товар, если он самый популярный в нескольких группах?

Comment: к первой попавшейся (они же отсортированы тоже по популярности)

Comment: Я бы решал в рамках хранимой процедуры - с курсором и временной таблицей внутри. Да, кстати... а что делать, если ВСЕ товары очередной категории уже задействованы для вывода в более популярных категориях?

Comment: можете помочь ссылкой на раскрытие темы или примером кода? Я ещё начинающий)

Comment: >>>что делать, если ВСЕ товары очередной категории уже задействованы для вывода в более популярных категориях? - такое не возможно, товаров много, но на будущее вопрос хороший

Comment: *такое не возможно* Структура данных подобное допускает (равно как допускает категории без товаров вообще). Следовательно, возможно, и это, как и необходимость обработки такой ситуации, не обсуждается.

Comment: Также структура, вероятно, допускает и равные популярности двух категорий или двух товаров в одной категории. Необходимо (тоже не обсуждается) сформулировать однозначный критерий выбора одной записи из двух формально равных.

Comment: Примерный сценарий того, что *невозможно*. В БД импортируются или вводятся данные. Новая категория уже в таблице, товары из неё - ещё нет. А юзер открывает страницу... упс... PS. Обратный ввод (сначала товары) возможен лишь в случае отсутствия FK - а тогда лучше вообще не начинать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь без магии с переменными тут не обойтись. Нам надо санчала получить полную перемноженную выборку всех товаров во всех группах, отсортировать ее по популярности. Далее, по ходу строк помечать первый товар в группе, в случае если он не встречался ранее и запоминать в текстовой переменной, что такой товар уже был использован:

```
select cat_id, cat_name, item_id, item_name
  from (
    select y.*,
           @cgrp,
           @first:=if(@cgrp!=cat_id and find_in_set(item_id,@used)=0,1,0) first,
           @used:=concat(@used,if(@first,concat(',',item_id),'')),
           @cgrp:=if(@first,cat_id,@cgrp)
      from (
        select c.id cat_id,c.name cat_name, c.popularity cat_p, i.id item_id, i.name item_name, i.popularity item_p
          from cats c, items i, cats2items ci, (select @cgrp:=0,@used:='',@first:=0) x
         where ci.cat_id=c.id and ci.item_id=i.id
         order by c.popularity desc, c.id, i.popularity desc
      ) y
  ) z
 where first=1
 order by cat_p desc, item_p desc
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a147e87/2). Обратите внимание, в категории 4 запрос не вывел ни одной строки, так как оба товара, которые есть в этой категории, ранее уже были выведены в других категориях. И это не лечится при данной постановке задачи, категории в которых мало товаров могут этим страдать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!! всё работает замечательно! А для 180 категорий и 53к товаров время выполнения 8-11 секунд это много или нормально?

Comment: @Mikhail Вообще много. С другой стороны и работы прилично. Если скажем каждый товар в 10 категориях, то мы получаем после перемножения таблиц 530к записей, а их еще отсортировать надо. А может дело в чем нибудь другом. попробуйте просто сделать `select count(1) from (самый внутренный подзапрос) x` т.е. посмотреть сколько времени будет выполняться именно внутренняя часть. И сколько записей он интересно покажет. И если так же медленно, то посмотреть план выполнения запроса, может каких полезных индексов не хватает ...